# Creating a Table on Tex Stack Exchange Question Editor

Tags: tables

I want to post a question on MSE, and I need to share the following 5×5 table

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
5  & 3  & 17 & 18 & 12 \\ \midrule
9  & 13 & 1  & 25 & 23 \\
6  & 19 & 20 & 2  & 21 \\
16 & 14 & 15 & 8  & 7  \\
4  & 24 & 10 & 22 & 11 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I can do it in LaTeX, but how can I do it on MSE, because I cannot use the appropriate package there. Also I do not want to post an image for that. So I am looking for some guidance for the same.

I want to create this table in MSE Math Mode

[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico, Thank You

Comment: As Mico said in their answer: If this is about Math.SX, it is probably about MathJax which, altough it uses a LaTeX-like syntax, is not based on (La)TeX. Therefore this question is off-topic on this site in a strict sense ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet from the first to the second `$` symbol should get you most of the way to your goal on Math.SE. The first two lines of code and the final one are only needed to make the code snippet compilable as a LaTeX document.

Math.SE doesn't actually use LaTeX to render the LaTeX-like code. Instead, it uses MathJax. MathJax technology is completely different from the TeX engine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
5  & 3  & 17 & 18 & 12 \\ \hline
9  & 13 & 1  & 25 & 23 \\ \hline
6  & 19 & 20 & 2  & 21 \\ \hline
16 & 14 & 15 & 8  & 7  \\ \hline
4  & 24 & 10 & 22 & 11 \\ \hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]